# How do I get my PI to beep on my monitor speakers

Tags: audio

I am putting together a motion sensor and camera.  To test the effectiveness of the motion sensor, I would like to temporarily have the system make a beep in the speaker which is integral to my monitor connected via a HDMI cable to the Pi.

I would be grateful for help in how I go about programming this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you been able to play other audio from the monitor speakers? Perhaps try playing an audio file with a media player to test. If that works, then all you'll have to do is generate a beep in your favourite programming language. Otherwise, it'd be useful if you could [edit] explaining what happens when you try to play audio.

Comment: The monitor speakers work with my Windows PC. I've only just started working with the PI. I've set up the night vision system with an IR camera and a PIR sensor at a very basic level hich works.  I would like ot tet the moition sensor by having a beep every time it picks up movement.  I have no idea how to go about this, and hope that someone can provde me with simple code.

Comment: Have you even bother to search for an answer/code?

Answer (score 1):

Does the display have on-board speakers? If so, audio should play back over HDMI without any special configuration.

Comment: Yes the display has on-board speakers.  But I don't know how to generate audio from the Raspberry Pi.  I was hoping there might be some simple command whihc would generate a sound.  I've found out how to get the sound to go via the HDMI.  I just need the sound now!

Comment: If I play videos using ```omxplayer /path/to/video.mp4``` to my TV using an HDMI cable, the audio plays through the TV speakers with no additional configuration. Audio playback goes through the TV speakers as well.